# Angular, Transloco, Jest Unit Testing Warning

Tags: angular, unit-testing, warnings, ts-jest

I have an Angular project.

```
inputValidatorsParamMap: Map<string, ValidationParams> = new Map([
  [
    'noMoreThan100Symbols',
    {
      regex: /^.{0,100}$/,
      message: this.translocoService.translate('MAIN_LAYOUT.MAX_CHARACTER_COUNT', {
        count: 100,
      }),
    } as ValidationParams,
  ],
]);
```

As you can see here, I set count dynamically.

The code works fine. And I get expected output.

But when I run `npx jest`, there is a warning message

Warning message:
Missing translation for 'enUS.MAIN_LAYOUT.MAX_CHARACTER_COUNT'

```
message: this.translocoService.translate('MAIN_LAYOUT.MAX_CHARACTER_COUNT', {
```

I do not use enUS and my browser language is not en-US
But I do not think it is due to spec.ts.
I have two languages 'en' and 'ru'
My spec.ts looks like this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { TranslocoService } from '@ngneat/transloco';

import { TranslocoRootModule } from '../../../transloco-root.module';
import { MyModalComponent } from './my-modal.component';

describe('MyModalComponent', () => {
  let component: MyModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, TranslocoRootModule],
      declarations: [MyModalComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [NgbActiveModal, TranslocoService],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**How to fix this warning message?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is logged due to the default setting for `missingHandler.logMissingKey` which defaults to `true`. You're importing the `TranslocoRootModule` which comes with defaults that are not intended for unit testing. There is a dedicated module meant for unit testing, `TranslocoTestingModule`, which loads the translations synchronously.

Best would be to follow [the guide on unit testing from the docs](https://jsverse.github.io/transloco/docs/unit-testing).